# Getting a A Lot of Duplicate Values When iterating

Tags: python

I am trying to query a table to find duplicate values for the last 7 days based on two columns (row4, and row0). Then print out "There are dups" or there are no dups. Im am testing it and the "else" condition is running even though in my table there are duplicates. Not sure what is wrong with my code.

```
# Loop through last 10 days in the summary bill confirmation DB
        day_delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        qselectall = '''select account_number, proc_date, email_address, cy_day,to_char(load_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') from sumb_email_conf'''
        dupcursor.execute(qselectall)
        start_date = datetime.date.today()
        end_date = start_date + 7 * day_delta


        # Check if there is a file inside the folder
        if os.listdir('\\\MyDataNEE\\user$\\bxt058y\\Desktop\\SUMB\\Summary Billing Emails'):
            # Loop through each account that has the last FPL cycle day and send email to the corresponding account number.
            if extrareadayday_date not in extrareaddays:
                accounts_sheet = pd.read_excel("sumbaccounts.xlsx",
                                               sheet_name=0)
                df = DataFrame(accounts_sheet)
                email_address = df[df['cycle_day'] == current_cycle_day].email_address_test
                account_numbers = df[df['cycle_day'] == current_cycle_day].account_number
                account = False
                for account, email in zip(account_numbers, email_address):
                    for row in dupcursor.fetchall():
                        for eachday in range((end_date - start_date).days):
                            eachday = start_date - eachday * day_delta
                            if str(eachday) in row[4] and account == row[0]:
                                account = True
                                print("There are dups")
                            else:
                                print("There are no dups")
                                sql = '''INSERT INTO sumb_email_conf 
  (proc_date, cy_day, account_number, email_address, load_date)

  VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)'''
                                values = (yesterday, str(current_cycle_day), account, email,
                                            str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
                                insertcursor.execute(sql, values)
                                connection.commit()
```

Table Data:

```
account_num  proc_date   email_address      cy   load_date
01234-56789 2019-08-27  test@example.com    19  2019-09-03
09876-54321 2019-08-27  test@example.com    19  2019-09-03
44554-69782 2019-08-27  test@example.com    19  2019-09-03
```

Comment: could you please provide sample data form the table?

Comment: `range((end_date - start_date).days)` does not cover the last day. If you have 2 days, then `(end_date - start_date).days == 1`, and the `for` will cover only one day.

Comment: Also, `start_date - eachday * day_delta` seems wrong. Did you mean `start_date + eachday * day_delta` ?

Comment: @Rufat I just edited and added sample table data.

Comment: Could you provide real examples of data in the table and in the xlsx file when you encounter this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not optimal, but if we use it,
I think you should convert code like this:

```
# Loop through last 10 days in the summary bill confirmation DB
        day_delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        qselectall = '''select account_number, proc_date, email_address, cy_day,to_char(load_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') from sumb_email_conf'''
        dupcursor.execute(qselectall)
        start_date = datetime.date.today()
        end_date = start_date + 7 * day_delta


        # Check if there is a file inside the folder
        if os.listdir('\\\MyDataNEE\\user$\\bxt058y\\Desktop\\SUMB\\Summary Billing Emails'):
            # Loop through each account that has the last FPL cycle day and send email to the corresponding account number.
            if extrareadayday_date not in extrareaddays:
                accounts_sheet = pd.read_excel("sumbaccounts.xlsx", sheet_name=0)
                df = DataFrame(accounts_sheet)
                email_address = df[df['cycle_day'] == current_cycle_day].email_address_test
                account_numbers = df[df['cycle_day'] == current_cycle_day].account_number
                for account, email in zip(account_numbers, email_address):
                    accountPresent = False
                    for row in dupcursor.fetchall():
                        for eachday in range((end_date - start_date).days):
                            eachday = start_date - eachday * day_delta
                            if str(eachday) in row[4] and account == row[0]:
                                accountPresent = True
                                print("There are dups")
                                break
                            else:
                                pass
                                # print("There are no dups")
                    if not accountPresent:
                        print("There are no dups")
                        sql = '''INSERT INTO sumb_email_conf 
  (proc_date, cy_day, account_number, email_address, load_date)
  VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)'''
                        values = (yesterday, str(current_cycle_day), account, email, str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
                        insertcursor.execute(sql, values)
                        connection.commit()
```